# Get vector in SCNNode environment from touch location swift

Tags: ios, swift, vector, scenekit, scnnode

I have the position and orientation of my camera, the CGPoint touch location on the screen, I need the line (preferably vector) in the direction that I touched on the screen in my 3d SCNNode environment, how can I get this?
A code snippet would be very helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`SCNSceneRenderer.unprojectPoint(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522631-unprojectpoint) method for this.

This method, which is implemented by `SCNView`, takes the coordinates of your point as a `SCNVector3`. Set the first two elements in the coordinate space of your view. Apple describes the use of the third element:

> The z-coordinate of the point parameter describes the depth at which to unproject the point relative to the near and far clipping planes of the renderer’s viewing frustum (defined by its 
>   pointOfView
>    node). Unprojecting a point whose z-coordinate is 0.0 returns a point on the near clipping plane; unprojecting a point whose z-coordinate is 1.0 returns a point on the far clipping plane.

You are not looking for the location of these points, but for the line that connects them. Just subtract both to get the line.

```
func getDirection(for point: CGPoint, in view: SCNView) -> SCNVector3 {
    let farPoint  = view.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3Make(point.x, point.y, 1))
    let nearPoint = view.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3Make(point.x, point.y, 0))

    return SCNVector3Make(farPoint.x - nearPoint.x, farPoint.y - nearPoint.y, farPoint.z - nearPoint.z) 
}
```