# How do you get the point in ARKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

In ARKit, if you touch a point on screen, can you determine the location of the point says 1m away from this point?

Currently it seems either you detect a hit point

```
if let hit = sceneView.hitTest(touchLocation, types:.featurePoint).first {
  …
}
```

or you transform from center of the screen:

```
var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
translation.columns.3.z = -1
let transform = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
```

What I am looking for is 1m from the touch location.

Update: I did the change based on suggestion.

```
func getDirection(for point: CGPoint, in view: SCNView) -> SCNVector3 {
    let farPoint  = view.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(Float(point.x), Float(point.y), 1))
    let nearPoint = view.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(Float(point.x), Float(point.y), 0))

    return SCNVector3(farPoint.x - nearPoint.x, farPoint.y - nearPoint.y, farPoint.z - nearPoint.z)
}

func getCameraPosition() -> SCNVector3 {
    let transform = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform
    let pos = MDLTransform(matrix:transform!)
    return SCNVector3(pos.translation.x, pos.translation.y, pos.translation.z)
}
```

Then in the touches I changed to:

```
if let touchLocation = touches.first?.location(in:sceneView) {
  …
  let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
  let pos = getCameraPosition()
  let dir = getDirection(for: touchLocation, in: sceneView).normalized
  node.position = SCNVector3(pos.x + dir.x, pos.y + dir.y, pos.z + dir.z)
}
```

Based on the normalized extension in the comment. I can now see the SCNNode! Just not where the finger is pointed, off by a large margin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are tapping the screen you are basically specifying a direction. In 3D space you can get a direction from two points. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991038/get-vector-in-scnnode-environment-from-touch-location-swift/45033059#45033059) for a possible solution.

When you have the direction you need to normalize it (to make it 1m in length) and add it to the current camera position.

To normalize a vector you can use these extension

```
extension SCNVector3 {
    /// Returns the length of the vector
    var length: Float {
        return sqrt(self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y + self.z * self.z)
    }
    var normalized: SCNVector3 {
        let length = self.length
        return SCNVector3(self.x/length, self.y/length, self.z/length)
    }
}
```

### Edit:

This works fine for me:

```
func getCameraPosition(in view: ARSCNView) -> SCNVector3? {
    guard let lastFrame = view.session.currentFrame else {
        return nil
    }

    let position = lastFrame.camera.transform * float4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1)
    let camera: SCNVector3 = SCNVector3(position.x, position.y, position.z)

    return camera
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the view.unprojectPoint as mentioned but I didn't get anything appeared on screen. I updated the code above... what have I done wrong?

Comment: `getDirection` retuns the direction you are looking at. You need to normalize this vector so that it has the length of 1 m and then add it to the position of the camera to get the position 1 m in front of the camera

Comment: OK, I get camera position, add to the direction (I am not sure how to normalised yet... just to see the result), and nothing happened. Updated the codes in question.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good start - I can now see the nodes... but at the wrong location. Off by a large margin from where the finger is touched.

Comment: I have edited my answer, [this code works fine for me](https://github.com/orangenkopf/Drawing)

Comment: It works! Thanks! Like the new getCameraPosition method - compared to my method, this also preserved camera direction right?

Comment: A question: does this answer assume the distance always 1m away? if let's say it is 0.5m from the user, do you edit farPoint  = view.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(Float(point.x), Float(point.y), 1)) to use 0.5 instead of 1? I tried and the result seems strange.

Comment: After you normalize the direction it has a length of one. Multiply each element with your desired distance, eg 0.5 to get the point 0.5m away

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to find the distance from the camera to a real-world surface?

In that case, you want a hit test, as in the first code snippet in your question. `ARHitTestResult` provides a [`distance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arhittestresult/2867903-distance) property that should give you exactly what you're looking for.

---

If you're asking how to calculate a point that's exactly 1m from the camera (regardless of whether there's a real world surface there), but in line with a particular point on screen instead of along the camera's centerline... [orangenkopf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45298434/957768) is one avenue you could start investigating. Another would be to use hit testing to find a surface, then scale the resulting vector to 1m in length.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to use @orangenkopf method but I can't get anything on screen (code updated). The issue with 2nd approach: what if I didn't hit anything?

Comment: I am looking for the same. Like I have two point in 3d world with measure app. Now I want to convert it in 2D points   and need to draw line in 2D  (like preview what user has drawn) Space  I know I can use `projectPoint` to convert it to 2D point but how can I Draw line and get the distance ?

Comment: Distance is what you get by subtracting two 3D vectors. After projecting two 3D vectors into 2D screen space, you can use any 2D drawing tool to draw lines.